# Firebase add a new node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Capture of my database]

How to put these nodes inside a users node and make another one to store posts.
My database reference:

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformations);
```

Comment: try this : `databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push(userInformations);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following code:

```
databaseReference.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformations);
```

This means that all those objects will be hosted within the `Users` node. Please the new `child("Users")` added. In the same way you need to use for the posts.

Comment: Users node is not created yet! this code will create it if its not available?

Comment: Does it work? Are now all the user objects hosted under `Users` node?

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
    assigned: true,
    groupId: pir.groupId
 }
```

the object above is added to the object in firebase db as update

```
const refff = admin.database().ref(`pirs/${pir.pirId}`);
        return refff.update({
            assigned: true,
            groupId: pir.groupId
        })
            .then(() => {
                return { pir }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error updating data:", error);
                return { errror: error }
            });
```