# android: adding a new node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need to add a new node "Completed" under the parent which will eventually contain all the information from the node "Requests" at end of the ride.

So basically, I need to create node "Completed" first but its not adding it.

**database**

```html
{
  "Requests" : {
    "iowpxU6WKUWpzWJyfssSoOVCPFj2" : {
      ".priority" : "f8118c3k3v",
      "destination" : "221 Prince William St",
      "details" : {
        "driver" : "nYIAHSYimJMHbMkXqDt9PQ0U3Nf2",
        "location" : "27 Horsfield St",
        "request status" : "accepted",
        "ridePrice" : 3.75,
        "rideStatus1" : "arrived at pickup",
        "rideStatus2" : "rider in vehicle",
        "rideStatus3" : "destination bound",
        "rideStatus4" : "arrived at destination",
        "rider" : "iowpxU6WKUWpzWJyfssSoOVCPFj2",
        "riderPaid" : "true"
      },
  "Users" : {
    "Drivers" : {
      "nYIAHSYimJMHbMkXqDt9PQ0U3Nf2" : {
        "driver" : "nYIAHSYimJMHbMkXqDt9PQ0U3Nf2",
        "email" : "driver@me.com",
        "name" : "driver",
        "password" : "whatever",
        "phone" : "5551212",
        "rates" : "0"
      }
    },
    "Riders" : {
      "iowpxU6WKUWpzWJyfssSoOVCPFj2" : {
        "avatarUrl" : "",
        "email" : "rider@me.com",
        "name" : "rider",
        "password" : "whatever",
        "phone" : "5551313",
        "rates" : "0",
        "riderId" : "iowpxU6WKUWpzWJyfssSoOVCPFj2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**addNewNode**

```
private void addNewNode() { // TODO: ........ NOT ADDING NEW NODE :-| ..........

    Toast.makeText(this, "addNewNode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    DatabaseReference newNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Completed");
    newNode.child(riderId).push().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(DriverTripDetail.this, "addNewNode: onDataChange", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Any assistance on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196632/firebase-add-a-new-node

Comment: I have tried all these references and still does not add the node "Completed".  "Completed" will consist of all the items in Requests so do I need to use setValue?  I tried by doing this:  DatabaseReference newNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Completed").child(riderId);
        newNode.push().setValue(1); but this just adds: Completed: 1 to the db ... Sorry I am a noob at this and learning on my own and stack overflow :)

Comment: The Firebase Database stores values at paths. If there is no value, the path does not exist. Your code creates a reference to `/Completed/$pushID`. but doesn't set any value, so the path doesn't get created. Something like this will work: `ewNode.child(riderId).push().setValue(true)`, since it sets a value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that worked, appreciate your help ... onto the next challenge.

Comment: Good to hear Liz. I wrote it up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database stores values at paths. If there is no value, the path does not exist.

Your code creates a reference to `/Completed/$pushID`. but doesn't set any value, so the path doesn't get created. Something like this will work, since it sets a value:

```
newNode.child(riderId).push().setValue(true)
```